# In Brave New World, how does Mustapha Mond get his red lips?

Tags: character-analysis, aldous-huxley, brave-new-world

I never quite understood why Mustapha Mond had red lips. In Chapter 3 it states,

> On the fringe of the little group stood a stranger- a man of middle
> height, black-haired, with a hooked nose, full red lips, eyes very
> piercing and dark.

Most people in real life don't have red lips - if they don't wear any makeup over their faces. This is a curious question I have, like where did the red lips come from? He must have worn some form of lipstick or something.

Comment: People differ in their circulation; Mond's blood circulation was sufficient to make his lips noticeably red.

Comment: Could also be a sign of liver disease.